# Exposing a pointer in Boost.Python

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

I have this very simple C++ class:

```
class Tree {
    public:
        Node *head;
};
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(myModule)
{

   class_<Tree>("Tree")
        .def_readwrite("head",&Tree::head)
    ;

}
```

I want to access the head variable from Python, but the message I see is:

```
No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: Node*
```

From what I understand, this happens because Python is freaking out because it has no concept of pointers. How can I access the head variable from Python?

I understand I should use encapsulation, but I'm currently stuck with needing a non-encapsulation solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Of course, I find the answer ten minutes after asking the question...here's how it's done:

```
class_<Tree>("Tree")
    .add_property("head",
     make_getter(&Tree::head, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()),
     make_setter(&Tree::head, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()))
;
```

Comment: That doesn't sound correct. Most probably you want `return_internal_reference`.