# How to converter std::string* in boost.python?

Tags: c++, python, c, boost-python

How to converter std::string* in boost.python?I have to handle some data of c++ in python.The data may be big.So I return a pointer to python. But there are some errors.

## c++

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    A() {
        data="342342fgsf";
        ss=&data;
    }
    std::string *ss;
    std::string data;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(ctopy)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<A> ("A",init<>())
        .add_property(ss,&A::ss)
    ;
}
```

## python

```
import ctopy
t1=ctopy.A()
print t1.ss     #error.TypeError:No to_python (by-value) converter found for c++ type:std::string*
```

Comment: see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/python/doc/v2/faq.html#custom_string - maybe this helps?

Comment: Have a look at this, appears relevant.

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541446/exposing-a-pointer-in-boost-python?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just pass pointer. Use `pointer_wrapper`:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/v2/ptr.html